# Wu's antialias line algorithm with non-black background

Tags: java, math, colors, antialiasing

I've implemented [Wu's Antialias line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) and it works great on a black background. However, I've been running into an issue making the intensity work with other colors.

I've been doing my color blending like this.

```
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
        rgbNew[i] = (int) (rgb[i] * brightness + baseRgb[i] * (1 - brightness));
```

However, this only seems to work with black and white backgrounds (in other cases I get incorrect results like the image below). Any suggestions on what I am not taking into account?

[image: incorrect image]

Comment: What kind of not working do you get for backgrounds other than black and white?

Comment: Sounds like this is a type issue, where a double between 0 and 1 becomes an int and can then only be 0/1... Are you incorrectly mixing types?

Comment: http://imgur.com/QX5I5 is what it looks like. I do not believe this is a type issue (int Math).

Comment: Sounds silly, but are you sure all your RGB data triplets are the same way round?

Comment: What do you mean same way round?

Comment: I mean, RGB data going somewhere that's expecting BGR data, or similar

Comment: I take that back haha. My integer to RGB method seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up being my method, that decomposed an integer that represented color, was mixing up red and blue. The above color mixing is correct.